# Stockhistory function in excel

Tags: excel, function

I used the following function in excel,
`=STOCKHISTORY("XNSE:TCS",DATE(2022,6,10),DATE(2022,7,20),0,1,0,5,1)`
and the results are,

```
Date        Volume        Close
10-06-2022  15,27,582    ₹ 3,359.90 
13-06-2022  30,30,921    ₹ 3,219.60 
14-06-2022  26,11,493    ₹ 3,210.55 
15-06-2022  14,04,536    ₹ 3,206.30 
16-06-2022  20,32,028    ₹ 3,142.00 
17-06-2022  52,40,434    ₹ 3,088.90 
11-07-2022  69,74,600    ₹ 3,113.80 
12-07-2022  37,34,815    ₹ 3,084.70 
13-07-2022  38,63,530    ₹ 3,038.75 
14-07-2022  47,64,908    ₹ 2,998.75 
15-07-2022  45,74,806    ₹ 2,994.60 
18-07-2022  32,02,795    ₹ 3,063.50 
19-07-2022  18,65,074    ₹ 3,074.25 
20-07-2022  34,02,251    ₹ 3,164.80
```

I didnot get the data between 18/6 to 10/7. but the data is available for the specified period.
I get proper result if I use new workbook.
for some reason in the specified workbook some datas are missing.
Can someone explain why this happens?

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you check your data that all are true dates or there are few dates stored as text?

Comment: Please check that you don't have any hidden rows in the output range.

Comment: @Harun24hr, thank you. how do I check for true dates?

Comment: @FlexYourData, thank you. there are no hidden rows